# Xamarin CrossInAppBilling: Get all previously subscribed products, on-device

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, in-app-purchase, subscription

I'm using the Xamarin CrossInAppBilling library.

I want to get a list of **all products that the user has ever subscribed to, regardless of current subscription status**. I would like to do this entirely on-device. I understand that the data could be spoofed if not verified on a trusted server. That is okay for my purposes.

In other words, even if the user does not have a current subscription, but they previously subscribed to a product, I want to get that product.

If I understand the documentation correctly, on **iOS** I can obtain this data via:

```
CrossInAppBilling.Current.GetPurchasesAsync(ItemType.Subscription);
```

...and on **Android** I can use:

```
CrossInAppBilling.Current.GetPurchasesHistoryAsync(ItemType.Subscription);
```

I am basing this understanding on the documentation [here](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/CheckAndRestorePurchases.html), which says regarding `GetPurchasesAsync` (emphasis mine):

> On Android only valid on-going subscriptions will be returned (with
> the original purchase date). **iOS returns all receipts for all
> instances of the subscriptions.** Read the iOS documentation to learn
> more on strategies.

...as well as the IntelliSense for CheckPurchasesHistoryAsync, which says:

> Android only: Returns the most recent purchase made by the user for each SKU,
> even if that purchase is expired, canceled, or consumed.

The Android-only method seems clear enough. **Is my understanding of the GetPurchasesAsync method on iOS correct?** Thank you in advance!